# Cancer treatment through regulation of myeloid-derived suppressor cells

Tags: immune-system, medications, cancer

There are many ongoing clinical trials that leverage the power of the immune system to recognize tumor cells such as CD47 and PDL1/PD1, and even engineered T cells!

I ran across an immune cell type for the first time during graduate school applications while browsing faculty research interests. I have been researching cancer for 19 years. The cells, myeloid-derived suppressor cells (MDSCs), are considered a regulatory immune cell distinct from the well known T regulatory cells (Tregs). An an immune regulator cell, MDSCs increase interleukin 10 activity. MDSCs appear to have been researched for more than a decade.

Are there any clinical derivatives from MDSC research, i.e., clinical trials for cancer or vaccines to foreign antigens?